# Is there a firm estimate in the number of political prisoners Castro executed?

Tags: cuba

Pretty self-explanatory, how many political enemies did Fidel Castro execute?

Comment: Whether "the people" support an action is irrelevant to whether it is considered political persecution. The only thing relevant is if the actions are supported by prior law. (and not new laws crafted to punish "corruption" after the fact)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I won't quote all the sources listed [here](http://users.erols.com/mwhite28/warstat6.htm#Cuba59), but their TL;DR summary is

> ANALYSIS: The dividing line between those who have an ax to grind and those who don't falls in the 5,000-12,000 range.

The BBC has [this report](http://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-america-latina-38153673) (Spanish site, translated)

> The Miami-based Archivo Cuba organization points out, for example, that in the more than half a century of the Revolution , 3,116 people were shot and 1,166 others were extrajudicially executed , although it recognizes that it is "very difficult " to know the exact numbers.

I would say 4000 to 6000 is probably accurate, although that number is likely low due to the fact that Cuba doesn't exactly report its political executions or imprisonments.

Comment: I was writing an answer, but this sums it up pretty well so I guess mine won't add to much. I did find http://cubaarchive.org, which has a lot of detailed information ([nice overview here](http://cubaarchive.org/home/images/stories/1.25.2012_update.pdf) for example).